# Find record in table Delayed::Job. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

How can I do a search by id( raw_attributes: id: 75)

I can save jobs, but I can not find them for editing

I tried Delayed::Job.where('handler LIKE ?', 'id:75')
But it does not find this record

table delayed_jobs

field handler contains

```
    --- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer
object: !ruby/class 'ReminderMailer'
method_name: :reminder_email
args:
- !ruby/object:Task
  raw_attributes:
    id: 75
    user_id: 6
    name: '1'
    done: false
    description: '12'
    reminder: &3 2017-06-02 10:47:00.000000000 Z
    priorities: 2
    created_at: &4 2017-06-02 10:25:00.000000000 Z
    updated_at: &6 2017-06-02 10:25:00.000000000 Z
  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet
```

Help me please

Comment: @VrushaliPawar, does not work

Comment: `Delayed::Job.where("handler like (?)", "%id: 75%")` try this

Comment: @VrushaliPawar, yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Delayed::Job.where("handler like (?)", "%id: 75%")
```

When you are using like, you should use `%%` sign with correct criteria.